# Procedure or function 'usp_UserAddNewUser' expects parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, insert

I wrote a stored procedure, but I get an error. Please guide me, how to get rid of that?

> error:(Procedure or function 'usp_UserAddNewUser' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied.)

Code:

```
create proc usp_UserAddNewUser
    (@FirstName nvarchar(50),
     @LastName  nvarchar(50),
     @Email nvarchar(50),
     @ContactNumber nvarchar(50),
     @Address nvarchar(50),
     @UserName nvarchar(50),
     @Password nvarchar(50) )
as 
begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration] ([FirstName], [LastName],
                                      [Email], [ContactNumber],
                                      [Address], [UserName], [Password])
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName,
            @Email, @ContactNumber,
            @Address, @UserName, @Password)
end
```

Comment: How are you **calling** this stored procedure? That's most likely where the problem is - this code is fine

Comment: I also think that's the problem, what I'm giving him is an alternative if he wants to pass a single parameter, given that the table where he retrieves the values is in a single table. But if this would be from a code, that's a different story.

Comment: @mar yeah now i've been fixed my issue thankx for reply

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I found your problem,

what you gave me is this:

```
USE [MVC4DB] GO DECLARE return_value int EXEC   return_value = [dbo].[usp_UserAddNewUser] SELECT    'Return Value' = return_value GO
```

The correct syntax for my example would be

```
exec usp_UserAddNewUser 'Joker','TheJoke','Joking@Joker.com','12345678','At my cave','Mr.J','Secret'
```

for your example, you can not insert a select statement into a stored procedure because your stored procedure would require the parameters you created.

If you would really want your stored procedure to be as what you want< i would revise your code like so.

```
create proc usp_UserAddNewUser
           (@FirstName)
as 
begin
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Registration]
               ([FirstName]
               ,[LastName]
               ,[Email]
               ,[ContactNumber]
               ,[Address]
               ,[UserName]
               ,[Password])
 VALUES
     select [FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[ContactNumber],[Address],[UserName],[Password] from employee where firstname = @FirstName
end
```

Do take note that with this syntax, you are open for SQLi attacks, please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) regarding sp_executesql and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) for more information about sp_executesql and Sql injection

Comment: USE [MVC4DB]
GO

DECLARE return_value int

EXEC return_value = [dbo].[usp_UserAddNewUser]

SELECT 'Return Value' = return_value

GO

Comment: when i type 
exec usp_UserAddNewUser('Joker','TheJoke','Joking@Joker.com','12345678','At my cave','Mr.J','Secret')
then get error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Joker'.

Comment: could i plz get ur skype id? i need ur help

Comment: i did with ur above mentioned code but problem remains same. i could get ur skype id? plz

Comment: Sorry, I'm still busy with work, but, could I ask where do you get the data to be inserted? specifically the values of the insert statement? I'm guessing its from a single table. And your code on how you pass your parameters into the stored procedure.

Comment: i've been fixed it. Thanku for gave ur precious time.
 actually m using this procedure in my MVC application for registration page. But now thank God resolved the issue